# CloudKit 'Unexpected Server Error' Anytime Manual Operations Performed in Dashboard

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckrecord

I have been developing an `iOS` app that utilizes the `CloudKit` feature available for Apple Developers.  I've found it to be a wonderful resource, especially since the very day I started designing my backend, the service I was intending to use (Parse) announced it was shutting down. It's very appealing due to it's small learning curve, but I'm starting to notice some annoying little issues here and there so I'm seeking out some experts for advice and help.  I posted another `CloudKit` question a couple days ago, which is still occurring: [CloudKit Delete Self Option Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464483/cloudkit-delete-self-option-for-ckreference-doesnt-work). But I want to limit this to a different issue that may be related.

**Problem** ~ Ever since I started using `CloudKit` I have noticed that whenever I manually try to edit (delete an entry, remove or add part of a list, even add a `DeleteSelf` option to a `CKReference` after creation), and then try to save the change, I get an error message and cannot proceed.  Here is a screenshot of the error window that appears:

[image: Unexpected Server Error]

It's frustrating because anytime I want to manipulate a record to perform some sort of test, I either have to go do it through my app, or just delete the record entirely and create a new one (that I am able to do without issue). I have been just working around this issue for over a month now because it wasn't fatal to my progress. However, I am starting to think that this could be related to my other `CloudKit` issues, and maybe if I could get some advice on how to fix it I could also solve my other problems. I have file numerous bug reports with Apple, but haven't received a response or seen any changes.

I'd also like to mention that for a very long time now (at least a few days), I've noticed down in the bottom left hand corner of my Dashboard that it is consistently saying that it's "Reindexing Development Data". I remember at first that wasn't an issue, I would get that notification after making a change but it'd go away after the operation is complete.  Now it seems to be stuck somewhere inside the process. And this is a chronic issue, it's saying this all the time, even right when I log into my dashboard.
Here is what I'm talking about:

[image: Reindexing Development Data]

As time goes on I find more small issues with `CloudKit`, I'm concerned that once I go into production more problems could start manifesting and then I could have a serious issue. I'd love to stick with `CloudKit` and avoid the learning curve of a different service like Amazon Web Services, but I also don't want to set myself up for failure.

Can anyone help me with this issue, or has anyone else experienced it on a regular basis? Thanks for the advice and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pierce,

I found myself in a similar situation; the issue seemed to be linked to Assets; I had an Asset in my record definition. I and several other I noted reported the re-indexing issue on the apple support website and after about a month it eventually disappeared.

Have you tried resting your database schema completely, snapshot the definition; since you zap it completely and than reset, see inset.

[image]

Ultimately I simply created a new project, linked it to cloud kit and use the new container in my original app.

Comment: ~ Thanks for the response, I apologize for my delay. I wasn't able to check this for a whole day.  I will try resetting my schema and see if that solves the problem.  I know previously while developing this app, I had a problem where I had manually edited a CKNotification, and then afterwards I couldn't get any CKNotifications to register.  I reset everything back then and it solved the problem, so I'm confident your answer will work as well.  The only problem I have with that is, what do we do if an issue arises during production? We can't reset after deployment! It's worrisome.

Comment: One hopes that this sort of thing is a by product of the development process and that your application will be so bullet proof when it goes to production it won't upset the Apple CloudKit forest of servers.